# In C, why does (int*)&x[k] work as well as (int*)x[k] for a 2-D array x?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In the following code

```
 int x[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
 int* y1 = (int*)x[1];
 int* y2 = (int*)&x[1];

 int i;
 for(i=0; i < 3 ; i++)
 {
  printf("%i %i\n",y1[i],y2[i]);
}
```

why do y1 and y2 point to the same data?

I would think that x[1] is a pointer to the second row of data, so y1 should be the correct way to access it. The expression &x[1] is getting the address of the pointer to the second row of data, so why does y2 even work?

Answer (score 4):

Given the declaration

```
int x[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

the type of the expression `x[1]` is "3-element array of `int`".  Unless an array expression is an operand of the `sizeof` or `&` address-of operator, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, the type of the expression is converted to "pointer to T" and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

Therefore, in the declaration

```
int *y1 = (int *) x[1];
```

the cast is unnecessary; `x[1]` will automatically be converted to type `int *`, and `y1` will point to `x[1][0]`.

In the declaration

```
int *y2 = (int *) &x[1];
```

the array expression `x[1]` is an operand of the address-of `&` operator, so it isn't automatically converted to type `int *`.  The type of the expression `&x[1]` is "pointer to 3-element array of `int`", or `int (*)[3]`.  The cast is necessary in this case, since you can't implicitly convert a pointer to an array of T to pointer to T.  However, it's probably not what you want to do; converting a pointer to an array to a pointer to a scalar will probably lead to confusion on somebody's part.

Note that `x[1]` and `&x[1]` yield the same *value* (the address of the first element in the array is the same as the address of the array itself), but the *types* are different, which will matter for things like the `++` and `--` operators.

If you want to avoid the casts, rewrite those declaration as

```
int *y1      =  x[1];
int (*y2)[3] = &x[1];
```

Comment: Correct.  `x[1]` yields a pointer to the first value in the array `x[1]`, and `&x[1]` yields a pointer to the array `x[1]` *itself*.  Of course the array and the first element in the array are necessarily colocated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `x[1]` is an *array*, not a pointer. The funky detail here is that address of the array is the array itself :), so to say, as in:

```
int a[10] = {0};
assert(( int* )a == ( int* )&a);
```

#### Edit 0:

To answer your question in the comment: A line like `int a[XXX];` reserves a chunk of memory of size `sizeof( int ) * XXX`. Every time you use `a` to access that memory, `a` is replaced with the address of the first element. The compiler knows that address (or at least the offset of the first element from the data segment or from the stack frame). This eliminates the need for storing that address in a temporary, and then dereferencing that temporary to get to the memory itself. Compiler forms the expression with (almost) direct value of the address. Thus `a` here in a sense has no location to take address of, so to preserve the semantics the `&a` is short-circuited to just `a`.

On the other hand, if you pass `a` as a function argument it's *decayed* to a pointer.

All fun stuff. Get yourself this book to see more: ["Expert C Programming Deep C Secrets"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131774298)

Comment: I think this (the fact that ( int* )a == ( int* )&a) explains a lot of what I'm observing. Can you explain why this is true, i.e. why is 'a' and '&a' the same? Is this a side-effect of compilation rules, or is this something that the language wants to be true?

Answer (score 1):

Because a 2D array does not store the actual pointer of each rows. On the stack, only the address of the first element is stored. Since the `x` array has a fixed known size the offsets are calculated on compile time.

The expression `(int*)&x[1]` downgrades the array to a pointer, returning the same value.

The expression `x[1]` returns the address of the value `4` in memory. Using the & operator you are asking for the address of the address of the value `4`, which does not make much sense in this case.

Comment: Given the above, is either of the two methods (i.e. (int*)x[1] vs (int*)&x[1]) more "correct"?  Which syntax is the recommended one from a "good programming guidelines" point of view?

Comment: @egio, `y1` is the correct one. `y2` is invalid since a) the data type of the expression is `int**` but you are forcing a cast to an `int*`, b) unexistent reference: there is no place in memory storing the address of the reference to `x[1]`.

Comment: regarding "unexistent reference: there is no place in memory storing the address of the reference to x[1]", this is what makes me wonder why y2 works. Is the compiler just being intelligent enough to figure out what the user wants to do with (int*)&x[1], even though it is improper syntax ?

Comment: No, the type of the expression is `int (*)[3]`, not `int **`.